# Ownerdraw controls overlaps when main window is minimized

Tags: c++, winapi

I am creating a simple program and experimenting with ownerdraw controls, and came across this problem.

I have an ownerdraw button and a static ownerdraw background. The program seems to be working fine, but when I minimize the main window, the static background overlaps the button and it disappears completely until I hover my mouse over the button's location.

[image: Sample]

The background and button are both handled in `WM_DRAWITEM`:

```
case WM_DRAWITEM:
{
    self->OnDrawItem(lParam, wParam); //Buttons

    //Background Static control with round corner
    HWND base = GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_STATIC_FOOTER);
    HDC hdc = GetDC(base);
    HPEN nullPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(169, 169, 169));
    RECT rect;
    GetWindowRect(base, &rect);
    MapWindowPoints(NULL, base, (LPPOINT)&rect, 2);
    SelectObject(hdc, nullPen);
    RoundRect(hdc, rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom, 5, 5);
    SetBkColor(hdc, TRANSPARENT);
    DeleteObject(nullPen);
    return TRUE;
}
```

I tried to remove `SS_OWNERDRAW` from the static control, and its following code from `WM_DRAWITEM`. This appears to solve the problem, however I want the background to have a rounded corner and not a pointed one.

Comment: Why is there a static control responsible for rendering the background instead of handling `WM_ERASEBKGND`? Regardless, does the parent window have the `WS_CLIPSIBLINGS` window style set?

Comment: I'm not sure what to do with WM_ERASEBKGND. I added a static control to get a white background with rounded corners that's all, im not sure if that answers your question. I tried adding WS_CLIPSIBLINGS but it did not do anything.

Comment: @isetsdfse Why are you drawing on the static control on *every* `WM_DRAWITEM` message you receive? You should be doing that only for `WM_DRAWITEM` messages that are sent by the static control.  If you owner-draw other controls (ie, the buttons, etc), then DO NOT draw the static control for *their* messages, and vice versa.  You need to pay attention to the contents of the `DRAWITEMSTRUCT` struct that `WM_DRAWITEM` gives you. It provides important information about *which* `HWND` is being drawn, *which* `HDC` you need to draw onto, what the current draw state of that control is, etc.